# Abstract function in order to let choose to return promises or callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

I don't know maybe it's an antipattern.

Soon very young developers will join our developer team, and I would like to let them choose if they want to use the module with callback or Promises pattern.

**This function basically save data into the database. I repeat the db.insert flow in order to abstract the function, but is there an other way to do this?**

```js
function create(data, callback) {
  
  if(callback) {
     db.insert(data, function(err, doc) { 
         return callback(err, doc);
    });
    
    
  } else {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
      db.insert(data, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        return resolve(doc); 
      
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I would not necessarily call it an anti-pattern. Many libraries work this way. However, I would avoid mixing promises and callbacks within the same codebase, rather than letting individual developers decide. If your new developer is not comfortable with promises, s/he should learn them.

Answer (score 1):

I like the bluebird [.asCallback(...)](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html#ascallback) approach:

```
function somethingAsync(cb) {
  return somePromise().asCallback(cb);
}
```

...essentially, you return a promise *and* call a callback (if one was passed). Therefore, it can be used either way. If you don't want to adopt Bluebird, you can essentially do the same thing like this:

```
function somethingAsync(cb) {
  var promise = somePromise();
  if (!cb) return promise;

  promise.then(res => cb(null, res), err => cb(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement the callback and then use the `pify` module to add the promise.

Answer (score 0):

You could just implement the normal CPS (continuation passing style) function and include a generic `promisify` function that adapts cps functions to promise-returning functions.

```
function create (data, k) {
  db.insert(data, k)
}

function promisify (f) {
  return function (...args) {
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
      f (...args, function (err, result) {
        if (err)
          reject(err)
        else
          resolve(result)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

You can use it with the continuation like this

```
create (data, function(err, res) {
  if (err)
    // do something with the error
  else
    // do something with the result
})
```

Or you can use promises like this

```
promisify(create)(data)
  .then(res => {
    // do something with the result
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // do something with the error
  })
```

You'll notice that the `create` function is pretty redundant tho. There's really no need to wrap the `db.insert` like this. Instead, skip creating the `create` function and just use both like this

```
// for cps, use normal api
db.insert(data, function(err, res) { ... })

// for promises, use the wrapper
promisify(db.insert)(data).then( ... )
```